# Cannot resolve symbol 'GooglePlayServicesClient'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services, build.gradle

I am trying to migrate a project from Eclipse to Android Studio, the project can be build in Eclipse and was successful imported to Android Studio, however, I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'GooglePlayServicesClient'` error in Android Studio.

I followed the official tutorial to imported Google Play service in Android Studio, and an other package "`com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult`" that used in my project does not have same issue. Only '`GooglePlayServicesClient`' cannot be resolved.

[image: issue]

I have also tried clean and rebuild my project, but the problem persists. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

My `build.gradle`

```
...
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraryListViewAnimations')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.1-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look in your .classpath /. iml file? Can you see this dependency? Did you try to refresh dependencies in IDE? In which scope does  it happen? (main / test or runtime)

Comment: Sorry, I am new in Android Studio. Where is the .classpath / .iml file? I just found `dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2' }` inside my project `build.gradle` file. Is it correct? Should I add dependencies of my module `build.gradle` to my project `build.gradle`?

Comment: Sure you should add your dependecies in build.gradle. But your IDE use a plugin that reads this dependecies and writes it to the classpath file. I guess the new Android Studio based on Intellij so you should look for .iml. You can find it in your project root folder. The .classpath (Eclipse) or <modulename>.iml (Idea) are actually hidden.

Comment: After copy dependencies of my module build.gradle to the project build.gradle, I got `Gradle DSL method not found: compile()` error.

Comment: Watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2q7XGuH2Q-s Maybe it can be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve symbol GooglePlayServicesClient on new Android Studio Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303427/cannot-resolve-symbol-googleplayservicesclient-on-new-android-studio-project)

Comment: @fabricator I asked earlier than him... :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GooglePlayServicesClient is obsolete and no longer included in the Google Play Services 7.x library.  Google recommends using the [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) instead.

See [Accessing Google APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html) in the Android developer docs:

*"Note: If you have an existing app that connects to Google Play services with a subclass of GooglePlayServicesClient, you should migrate to GoogleApiClient as soon as possible."*

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'` to build.gradle?
You can find more guide [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install) . Hope this help.

Comment: Yes, I have this line in my build.gradle file.

Comment: i'm not sure why, but i saw it's duplicate two lines compile. You should choose latest version 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'

Comment: i just checked com.google.android.gms.common and saw class GooglePlayServicesClient. i'm not sure why you don't. Just get latest version and sync build gradle again.

Comment: Do you have any result on this ?