# Cannot resolve symbol GooglePlayServicesClient on new Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I just installed Android Studio 1.1.0 and created a new project. I created it with a Login Activity including Google+ login.

As soon as the project opens, I see many errors in `PlusBaseActivity.java`. These seem to stem around the fact that `com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServiceClient` is not being imported.

I have NOT changed the code at all and wonder why it isn't running by default. How can I get this to import?

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "us.grahn.logintest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: @PavelDudka I have included the build.gradle file. I have not edited this at all.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`GooglePlayServicesClient` class has been deprecated for some time. With latest GooglePlayServices release I believe they got rid of it completely.

However, demo project in AndroidStudio still uses old APIs, so it won't compile :(

Essentially, for talking to GooglePlayServices, you should use [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) now (as described here https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html)

Something like:

```
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

................

googleApiClient.connect();
```

Comment: Developing for Android is horrible.
I have to completey rewrite the project I am working on every few months because IDE and SDK changes completely break everything.
Already sitting another 5 hours on my project, trying to get it compile again with the updated IDE. I am so looking forward the iphone implementation

Comment: @John keep us posted

Comment: @John use clean architecture, this way you will only have to change code in one class.