# Location listener have problems to works in some devices and problems to migrate to FusedLocationListener

Tags: android, locationlistener, android-fusedlocation

I´ve the following code that get current location o device:

```
public class MapPlace extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    // location coordinates
    double dLatitude = 0.0;
    double dLongitude = 0.0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_place);

          if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
          {
               buildGoogleApiClient();
               mGoogleApiClient.connect();
          }

          MapFragment mapF = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
         if (mapF != null)
            mapF.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
        {
           mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
             .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
             .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
             .addApi(LocationServices.API)
             .build();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
           mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
           mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
           mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
           mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
           LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
         }

         @Override
         public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

         @Override
         public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

         @Override
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
         {
             mLastLocation = location;
             dLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
             dLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

         }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but in some devices is not working, to get success using this code I have to restart the device or close and reopen the activity, so I want to avoid this issue.

As recommend this [stack overflow aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17967530/4987172) I tried to migrate to LocationFusedLocation to solve this issue but I face some problems adding GooglePlayServicesClient implements in java class because this library is temporally deprecated as said this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29304047/4987172).
So... what can I do? Is there other way to do that?

Comment: the answer to that question for the second link shows you how to register for location updates the new way so follow that

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is move all of your code from onCreate() (except for setContentView())  to onResume(), and your problems should go away.

Comment: @DanielNugent ok, I´ll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're already using GoogleApiClient, so you don't need any help there.  Your code is already updated to the non-deprecated way of doing it.

Just a couple changes should solve your problems, and I see one more issue not mentioned.

First, you mention that you're having trouble with the Location listener, and that you need to re-start the Activity to get it working again.

To fix that, just move the code that connects the GoogleApiClient from onCreate() to onResume():

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
    {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    MapFragment mapF = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    //only call getMapAsync() again if mMap is null:
    if (mapF != null && mMap == null)
        mapF.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

The other issue is that you should un-register for Location updates in onPause(), so that your app doesn't continue to request location updates when the user leaves your app:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //added to stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

Here is the full class code that should work for you, note that I also added a GoogleMap reference, and set it in the onMapReady() callback (you may already have this in your full code):

```
public class MapPlace extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    // location coordinates
    double dLatitude = 0.0;
    double dLongitude = 0.0;

    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_place);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        MapFragment mapF = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //only call getMapAsync() again if mMap is null:
        if (mapF != null && mMap == null)
            mapF.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //added to stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        dLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        dLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I had done that in onPause but I forgot to put in my question, the only thing I needed was to set in onResume the code tha I put in onCreate, thanks