# Some Google imports can not be resolved by Android Studio

Tags: java, android, import, routes, trace

Android Studio can not resolve the following Imports in my activity for route tracing:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
```

although I installed Google APIs from Anroid SDK Manager and compile the following in dependencies in my build.gradle (Module:app)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2'
```

I would be thankful for any hints or help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved Check this.

Answer (score 0):

`GooglePlayServicesClient` is deprecated in new play service release. With the reference of : [Cannot resolve symbol GooglePlayServicesClient on new Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303427/cannot-resolve-symbol-googleplayservicesclient-on-new-android-studio-project)

`LocationClient` is replaced with the new `FusedLocationProviderApi`. With the reference of [Android play services 6.5: LocationClient is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372638/android-play-services-6-5-locationclient-is-missing)